# Serial connection with Arduino, PHP & OpenWrt. Bug?

Tags: php, serial-port, arduino, openwrt

I'm trying to create a PHP web interface to control Arduino Uno via USB interface on TP-Link MR3420 router using OpenWrt firmware

The weird thing is that my PHP script only get reply from arduino after running a python script that communicate with arduino

I'm sure that my PHP script is working since it was able to turn off leds on arduino but get no reply from arduino

Here is my PHP code:

```
require("lib/php_serial.class.php");

$serial = new phpSerial;

$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyACM0");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);

$serial->deviceOpen();
$serial->sendMessage($cmd);
sleep(1);
$read = $serial->readPort();
$serial->deviceClose();
```

Here is my arduino sketch:

```
int numSerial;
if (Serial.available() > 0)
{
char inByte = Serial.read();
switch (inByte)
{
case 'l':
  numSerial = numberFromSerial();
  if (numSerial >= 0)
  {
    Serial.print("LED Mode: ");
    switch (numSerial)
    {
    case 0:
      ledMode = 0;
      Serial.print("OFF");
      break;
    case 1:
      ledMode = 1;
      Serial.print("TEMP");
      break;
    case 2:
      ledMode = 2;
      Serial.print("KR");
      break;
    }
  }
  else
    Serial.print(ledMode);
  break;
case 't': //Data request
  Serial.print(getTemp());
  break;
}
}
```

And here is my python code:

```
    import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600, timeout=3)
ser.open()
ser.write("t")
print ser.readline()
ser.close()
```

Please help.
Thanks.

**Found the real source of the problem!**

In phpSerial Class:

`$ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " " . (int) $rate, $out);`

Replace with:

`$ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " raw speed " . (int) $rate, $out);`

Comment: SOLVED!

Running "stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw speed 115200" on every router startup solved my problem

Comment: If you solved your own problem you should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Found the real source of the problem!**

In phpSerial Class:

```
$ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " " . (int) $rate, $out);
```

Replace with:

```
$ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " raw speed " . (int) $rate, $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino has a documented [Auto Reset on Serial Connection](http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection) issue.  My first guess would be that you are triggering this with the PHP code (that's why the lights are turning off but you're not receiving any response back).

Try using one of the workarounds from the link above.

Here's a perl code snippet you could use to see if you are actually triggering this issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Device::SerialPort;
my $port = Device::SerialPort->new("/dev/ttyUSB0");
$port->databits(8);
$port->baudrate(9600); # <-- match to arduino settings
$port->parity("none");
$port->stopbits(1);
$port->dtr_active(0);  //toggle this to one to trigger reset
```

Comment: auto reset is already disabled using custom firmware from here: http://www.tinkerin.gs/2011/03/arduino-auto-reset-software-fix.html
but still no reply from arduino

Answer (score 0):

I use this line in my rc.local file to set up the port prior to running anything.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw speed 38400 -echo -hupcl
```

the two additional flags are useful:
-echo  switches off the OpenWRT/USB habit of echoing every output back on the input
-hupcl switches off the autoreset issue by not sending a hup after each transmission

There again YMMV - I am sending and receiving single bytes not strings or complex data